# Excel, importing incomplete data to a complete table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, import

I'm not sure if I'm asking this correctly, but here's my problem.

I'm managing the occupancy of a building, and the website we use lets us generate a report of the occupants by room. This information comes out in a CSV format. The data is sorted by room number, 101A, 101B, 102A, 103B, and so on... However, if a room is vacant it just omits the room entirely and that row of data doesn't exist in the CSV.

Ultimately I need to find a way to import this data from the CSV to populate a roster I'm maintaining in excel. I'm thinking the easiest way would be to somehow have excel fill in the vacant room information itself based on what's missing (maybe by comparing it to a pre-existing table)? I can't figure out how to do it though.

Data from CSV

[image: Data from CSV]

What I want the final table to look like after import to Excel

[image: What I want the final table to look like after import to Excel]

Comment: One simple method is,, after you get data been imported, put formula in `Occupant Column`  to check whether `Check in Date Cell is blank or not`, if is blank,  then set `VACANT` to display as `TRUE` option. And set `BLANK` for `Gender Column` ☺

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this is using Power Query. This is a free Microsoft Add-in for Excel 2010 and 2013 and included in 2016 and later as Get and Transform in the Data ribbon.

Prepare a complete list of rooms and keep it in a spreadsheet. then

- load the CSV data into Power Query and save it as a connection only (without loading it to the grid)
- load the room list into Power Query.
- From the room list query as the active query, merge the CSV query with the room list query, matching on the room number and using the setting "All from first, matching from second"
- expand the merged table

Play around with this concept. You can save the workbook and when you have a new CSV, save it with the same file name as the first one, then refresh the query.

One click. Magic.

Comment: ... and would the downvoter please explain what s/he does not like?